# What does it mean if we use eigenvetor matrix of centered matrix $\mathbf{X}$ to reduce the dimension of $\mathbf{X}$ without centering?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, centering

Recently, I was trying to use PCA to reduce the dimension of matrix $\mathbf{X}$.

Suppose a data matrix $\mathbf{X}\in \mathbb{C}^{M\times N}$, where $M$ is the number of variables and $N$ is the number of samples. The centered data matrix is denoted as $\mathbf{X}_m$. We can easily get the eigenvector matrix of covariance matrix $\mathbf{C}_{xm} \in \mathbb{C}^{M\times M}$ of $\mathbf{X}_m$ to re-express the original data matrix.

However, normally this projection is applied on the centered data matrix $\mathbf{X}_m$. if I use the eigenvetor matrix to process the data matrix $\mathbf{X}$ without centering, what will be the result?

For example, if I choose first $K$ column of eigenvector matrix $\mathbf{P}$ (eigenvalues in descending order) to reduce the dimension of data matrix $\mathbf{X}$, we can get $\mathbf{X}_{new}\in \mathbb{C}^{K\times N}=\mathbf{P}^{H}(:,1:K)\mathbf{X}$ with lower dimension. But is it right? Can it express the data matrix with lower dimension without centering? What's the difference between this one and the outcome of data matrix $\mathbf{X}_m$ with centering?

---

Edit: I think my problem can be revised as "If I want to reduce the dimension of data matrix $\mathbf{X}$ ($\mathbf{X}\in \mathbb{C}^{M\times N}$, $M$ is the number of variables and $N$ is the number of snapshots) without centering, what should I do?"

Comment: There is no general relationship between PCA of $X$ and PCA of $X_m.$  You can see this for yourself by drawing some point clouds on a sheet of paper.  Draw an elliptically shaped cloud centered at the origin.  Plot its PCs.  Now shift the entire cloud a long distance in some direction that does not coincide with one of the PCs.  What happens to the PCs when you do this?

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the comment. So if  I want to reduce the dimension of $\mathbf{X}$ that without centering, should I just perform PCA on X, where covariance $\mathbf{C}_x=\frac{1}{N-1}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^H$?

Comment: That's basically right--but bear in mind that PCA is ordinarily performed with a direct analysis of $X$ itself (using the SVD).

Comment: @whuber Thanks! I will try to perform PCA on $\mathbf{X}$ without centering using SVD.

Comment: Maybe not. PCA on covariance matrix of $X$ is  equivalent with the SVD of $X_m$. Intuitively speaking, PCA is a algebraic method to find some specific directions centered on the mean, not the origin.

Comment: @HJLiang  Thanks for the comment! Then, if I want to reduce the dimension of $\mathbf{X}$, what should I do?

Comment: @tyrela Perform SVD on centered $\mathbf{X}$, that is, firstly, center each column of $\mathbf{X}$, and denote $\bar{\mathbf{X}} = \mathbf{1}_{n\times n}\mathbf{X}/n$. Secondly, let the SVD of $\mathbf{X} - \bar{\mathbf{X}} = UDV^{\intercal}$, where the singular values in $D$ are sorted in descending order. Thirdly, let $V_k$ be the first k part of $V$ (and the same for $U_k$ and $D_k$), then $XV_k = U_kD_k + \bar{\mathbf{X}}V_k$ is the data after dimensionality reduction, where $\bar{\mathbf{X}}V_k$ is the new mean after dimensionality reduction.

Comment: @HJLiang  Really thanks for your help! I will try this procedure. Sorry for replying so late.

Comment: @HJLiang Sorry to bother you again!  Should this centering be done for each row? Center each column seems to average different variables under each sample.

Comment: @tyrela Yes! Do centering for each row in you case $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times N}$. ( My answer is based on $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times p}$ where $n$ observations and $p$ variables)

Comment: @HJLiang Thanks! I will try it.